# Using Azure Active Directory to access other services

Tags: azure, authentication, sharepoint, authorization, azure-active-directory

I have azure active directory authentication in my Web API and I want to connect to other services as Dynamics NAV and Sharepoint using azure ad credentials.

The code to access Sharepoint is the following:

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(Email, Password);
```

And the code to access the Dynamics NAV is the following:

```
NAV.NAV nav = new NAV.NAV(URL);
nav.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Email, Password, Domain);
```

The problem is that I have to enter manually user credentials to access the Sharepoint and NAV services. Is there any way to do this dynamically? Using entered azure ad credentials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, the Dynamics NAV supports OAuth authentication with Azure Active Directory. In this scenario, you can use the **on-behalf-of flow** which requires users enter the username/password to get the access token to access the web API. Then the web API can exchange the access token for Dynamics NAV and call the Dynamics NAV. Here is a figure to demonstrate this scenario(refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios)): 
[image]

And for the SharePoint, you can use Microsoft Graph. More detail about oauth for the Dynamics NAV and Microsoft Graph, you can refer the link below:

[Using OAuth to Authenticate Microsoft Dynamics NAV Web Services (OData and SOAP)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt634540(v=nav.90).aspx)

[Get access tokens to call Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_overview)

And for the code sample for the on-behalf-of flow, you can refer the code sample below:

[active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof)

Comment: Hmm @Fei Xue - MSFT, we have a microsoft dynamics crm online system where we use PHP to authenticate over OAuth against the https://login.microsoftonline.com/ authority. We can perform CRUD requests and now we want to store documents in the connected sharepoint site. Is there a way to re-use the Access-Token. In my opinion this token was granted only for dynamics. I have no idea where to start and digg deeper and would be happy to have some guidance here. People do not operate out of the dynamics GUI and thats why we need an API solution here